# jQuery open element in 1 element

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is a very simple thing, but I cannot get it work. I am making a lead management dashboard where a user can watch his leads. He first sees only the number, name and date of the lead and when he clicks on the name another div needs to show up to see the other information.

Normally I can use `.closest()`, but I think because they are on the same level that doesn't work. So I tried `.siblings()` but that even doesn't work.

Can someone help me with this?

I made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zeSj3/

```
// Open en close leads
$("#dash_action #lead_list .lead_line a").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('.lead_info').fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.parents()` to find the nearest common parent (`.parents(".lead_line")`) and then `find()` from there.

```
$(this).parents(".lead_line").find('.lead_info').fadeToggle();
```

Avoid using multiple calls of `.parent()`. It's not as easy to understand which element it's referencing, and any slight changes to the structure of the DOM will break your script.

http://jsfiddle.net/zeSj3/1/

Answer (score 1):

you should use.

```
 $("#dash_action #lead_list .lead_line a").click(function () {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.lead_info').fadeToggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's two levels above, so you should call `parent()` twice.

```
// Open en close leads
$("#dash_action #lead_list .lead_line a").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.lead_info').fadeToggle();
});
```

[Link to JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zeSj3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
// Open en close leads
$(".lead_line a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().closest('.lead_line').find('.lead_info').fadeToggle();
});
```

But as mentioned in one of the answers, `.parents()` is probably a better solution.